# Netsuite record.load

Tags: load, netsuite, record

I can load a record with a hardcoded ID, but I'm not sure how to get this dynamically during a create on after submit method for a user event script. This code is in an if block for UserEventType create. Is there some variable to use for id for newrecord?

thank you

```
            var Bill = record.load({
                type: record.Type.VENDOR_BILL, 
                id: 13295,
                isDynamic: true
                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On create the record id is not available until the after submit phase. There you can get it from the newRecord

```js
function afterSubmit(context){
    const newRec = context.newRecord;
    const billRec = record.load(
        type:newRec.type,
        id:newRec.id,
        isDynamic:true
    });
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks again bknights, I just literally found this out and posted too. I appreciate your help. Learning alot, much appreciated sir!

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it helps someone else. I was able to get the internal id and load the record like this:

```
            var recordId = scriptContext.newRecord.id;
            
            log.audit({ title: 'NEW', details: recordId });

            // get bill to index
            var Bill = record.load({
                type: record.Type.VENDOR_BILL, 
                id: recordId,
                isDynamic: true
                });
```